# Node.js and mongodb from api variable nr of entries - one big db entry or each as own?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making an application that reads a json api then saves that data to mongodb database.

Example of json would be:

```
0:
    name: john
    age: 30
1:
   name: freda
   age: 40
2:
   name: lisa
   age: 25
```

I would like to save it as a single entry in database

```
id: 1  (id is same for all entries in single "api read", I get it from elsewhere)
name0:john
age0:30
name1:freda
age1:40
name2:lisa
age2:25
```

Problem is that number of entries varies and I don't know how to write them as one entry in database.
What I have working now is to loop through the json data - "data" and then write each as own entry.

```
            new Char({
                id: data.id,
                name: data[i].name,
                age: data[i].age, 
            }).save()
```

model

```
const charSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    age: String,
    (would add more)
});
```

I can get anywhere between 1-50 entries in the response, so how could I store them in a single mongodb entry?

Maybe subquestion would be, is it better to keep them separated as own "persons"?
I will be then using another program to access data from mongodb. All I need is that I get all names connected to the single id that I will process in that app(also node.js). But what would be preferable if both are possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ig you will receive many entries and you want to save them into single Document , change your schema modeling :

```
const charSchema = new Schema({
id: String,
name: [String],
age: [String],
```

});